# Ansible: Better way of using set_fact

Tags: variable, ansible

I use following playbook:

```
~ # cat play.yml

- name: MAIN PLAY
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no

  vars:
    status:
      check1: present
      check2: ""

  tasks:
  - debug:
      var: status

  - name: Verify status
    set_fact:
      status_old: "{{status}}"
      status_new:
        check1: "{{'present' if status.check1 is defined and status.check1 != '' else 'absent'}}"
        check2: "{{'present' if status.check2 is defined and status.check2 != '' else 'absent'}}"
  
  - name: Combine facts
    set_fact:
      status: "{{status|combine(status_old, status_new, recursive=True) }}"

  - debug:
      var: status
```

Output:

```
PLAY [MAIN PLAY] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [debug] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "status": {
        "check1": "present",
        "check2": ""
    }
}

TASK [Verify status] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Combine facts] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "status": {
        "check1": "present",
        "check2": "absent"
    }
}
```

As you could see this works well, however second task `name: Combine facts` must be present in the play

## **Question:**

Is there a better way to verify if the variable exist and specific status can be set based on detected condition? 
The goal here is to get rid of task `name: Combine facts` and set everything under task `name: Verify status` but without using 'block'

I was trying also with this:

```
  - name: Verify status
    set_fact:
      status: "{{ status |combine(status_old, status_new, recursive=True) }}"
      vars:
        status_old: "{{status}}"
        status_new:
          check1: "{{'present' if status.check1 is defined and status.check1 != '' else 'absent'}}"
          check2: "{{'present' if check2 is defined and check2 != '' else 'absent'}}"
```

but in the output there is now change

```
TASK [debug] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "status": {
        "check1": "present",
        "check2": ""
    }
}
```

and if I 'set_fact' as

```
- name: Verify status
  set_fact:
    status:
      check2: present
```

than `status.check1` is gone

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "status": {
        "check2": "present"
    }
}
```

Any sugestions?

Comment: There is an error in your playbook; you are checking `if check2 is defined`, where I think you mean `if status.check2 is defined`.

Comment: that is true I is corrected now, thanks for pointing out

Answer (score 1):

There's no reason to set `status_old` and `status_new` and then
combine them. You can simply replace the value of `status` in your
`set_fact` status.  Instead of this:

```
  - name: Verify status
    set_fact:
      status_old: "{{status}}"
      status_new:
        check1: "{{'present' if status.check1 is defined and status.check1 != '' else 'absent'}}"
        check2: "{{'present' if status.check2 is defined and status.check2 != '' else 'absent'}}"
  
  - name: Combine facts
    set_fact:
      status: "{{status|combine(status_old, status_new, recursive=True) }}"
```

Just do this:

```
  - name: Verify status
    set_fact:
      status:
        check1: "{{'present' if status.check1 is defined and status.check1 != '' else 'absent'}}"
        check2: "{{'present' if status.check2 is defined and status.check2 != '' else 'absent'}}"
```